# Build Metadata File (txt file) containing JSON

Tags: ruby, json, templates

I am building a command line app that will generate metadata files amongst other things. I have a series of values that I want included, and I would like to insert those values into json format and than write it to a .txt file.

The complicated part (to me at least) is some of the values are dynamic (i.e. they may change everytime a file is created), other parts of the json file will need to be static. Is there any sort of templating that may help with this? (json erb)

If I were to use a json erb template, how would I write the result of the template (after it has been populated) to a txt file since this is not a rails app and I thus would not be calling the view.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like two things could be helpful to you, but your question is pretty open ended ...

First, if your json templates are complex (static and dynamic parts?) I suggest you look at a tool like RABL ...

https://github.com/nesquena/rabl

There is a railscast on RABL here:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/322-rabl

RABL lets you create templates for generating custom JSON output.

Regarding writing to a file, you may or may not need to call the controller first. But the flow would be something like:

```
 #sample_controller.rb
 require 'json'
 def get_sample
      @x = {:a => "apple", :b => "baker"}
      render json: @x 
 end
```

You can call the controller and get the rendered json.

```
 z = get_sample
 File.open(yourfile, 'w') { |file| file.write(z) }
```